# Why does TortoiseSVN still show files in Excluded directories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to keep the Expression Web  editing files from showing up in TortoiseSVN.

I added _vti_cnf [folder] to the Ignores List (and disabled the Config File so it didn't overwrite /overule the Tortoise settings)

[image]

But files in that folder still shows up in the list.

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have added them to the repository, so that they now shows as missing. Select the files in the working copy, do a right click and select TSVN->delete. Now commit this change. Now all new files in the folder are ignored.